# Difference between request encoded text and content

Tags: python, arrays, python-requests

Keep in mind I'm completely new to python so this is probably something simple.
I thought that the `content` field was just the binary data while the `text` field was said binary data represented as a utf-8 string. But when I try to convert the text back to bytes and compare the output it returns false.

```
response = requests.get("https://some.url.com/14")

content = response.content
text = response.text

TextBytes = bytes(text,'utf-8')
print(len(TextBytes) == len(content)) # False
print(TextBytes == content) # False
```

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0):

one is in bytecode and one is in text
Content is for the actual binary from the text. when this is printed it is decoded but exactly. For example when I `print(content)`...

```
>>> print(content)
b'{\n  "userId": 1,\n  "id": 1,\n  "title": "delectus aut autem",\n  "completed": false\n}'
```

Notice there is a `b`. This b says that the following printed object is not a string but binary. This also causes escape sequences to not work when printed because it is part of the bytes, not text. This would be useful if you were downloading an executable, for example.

The difference is that `text` is the actual text response and acts like text. Escape sequences work and it does not have the `b` that `content` had.

```
>>> print(text)
{
  "userId": 1,
  "id": 1,
  "title": "delectus aut autem",
  "completed": false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/api/):

content:

> Content of the response, in bytes.

text:

> Content of the response, in unicode.

> If Response.encoding is None, encoding will be guessed using chardet.

(note: `None` is default.)

> The encoding of the response content is determined based solely on HTTP headers, following RFC 2616 to the letter. If you can take advantage of non-HTTP knowledge to make a better guess at the encoding, you should set r.encoding appropriately before accessing this property.

As you can see, you cannot be sure about how it is encoded, unless you specifically set it.